# how to properly read from stream in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am reading from the shared memory a stream producing an infinite information output such as:

```
0x1 (TimeStamp) 12Bytes:11216 +     1771/(47999+1) (0.036896) delta= 0+    1536/(47999+1) (0.032000) 11216.013361 23.534ms 2015.06.25 11:51:16.525
0x4 (ReferenceTime) 12Bytes:11215 + 24786286/(26999999+1) (0.918011) delta= 0+  806359/(26999999+1) (0.029856) 11216.013376 -95.366ms 2015.06.25 11:51:16.525
0x6 (ProcessDelay) 4Bytes: 32 (0x20)
0x7 (ClockAccuracy) 8Bytes: offset=0.000ppm (+-0.000ppm)
0xb (ClockId) 8Bytes: 01 00 00 00 42 22 01 00
0x20001 (SampleRate) 4Bytes: 48000 (0xbb80)
0x20002 (Channels) 4Bytes: 6 (0x6)
0x20003 (PcmLevel) 24Bytes: -11041 -11541 -49076 -86121 -24846 -24382
0x20004 (PcmPeak) 24Bytes: -8088 -8697 -37244 -84288 -21437 -21769
0x2000e (DolbyDpMetadata) 39352Bytes:
Linear Time: 11216 +     1771/(47999+1) (0.036896) delta= 0+    1536/(47999+1) (0.032000)
```

if i try to read the stream with the following command:

```
while read line; 
do 
    echo "$line";
    echo "im here!"
done < <(../tools/spucat adec-68)
```

where`spucat` is a cpp binary exacutable that continuosly print out on console using printf() information about incoming data packets.

this is the result:

```
im here!
�k�G��E�x����b��h�������c����2��/n��-�U���QE�L�x���c�������������������������������x��4����O��M�����/��(������������������~��E�*�������;
im here!
������r��$�|��J�n�P�4�
```

if i start the script whit this command:

```
while read line; 
do 
    echo "$line";
    echo "im here!"
done < $(../tools/spucat adec-68)
```

it actually never go inside the while loop, just start to print out the stream whaiting for the end.
Is tehere a way to read it line by line and process it inside the while loop?

Comment: That looks like binary data, not text.  How is this stream produced, is it text?

Comment: Yes, is a echo dump.

Comment: @mattobob What do you mean with *echo dump*?

Comment: Sorry, `spucat` is a cpp binary exacutable that continuosly print out on console using printf() information about incoming data packets.

Comment: Try `../tools/spucat adec-68 | while ...`

Answer (score 1):

`spucat` is dumping to the standard error (no idea why), so to processing it must be redirect to the standard output:

```
while read -r line; 
do 
    echo "$line";
    echo "im here!"
done < <(../tools/spucat -p 4 adec-68  2>&1 > /dev/null)
```